# Launched browser intent for DRM content immediately jumps to background

Tags: android, browser, android-intent

I have an app that launches a browser with a VIEW intent pointing at a URL containing DRMed content (which the browser should then download into the DrmStore). This works perfectly the first time, but on subsequent attempts to download the same file, the browser opens, pops up a dialog saying the content has previously been downloaded and prompting for overwrite and *immediately* drops into the background, bringing the original app back to the foreground.

Why does this happen in this very specific case, and is there any way of working around it (ie. leaving the browser in the foreground)?

Edit: This has been observed on an HTC Desire; it seems like the text in the dialog is an HTC message rather than a core Android one, so the issue may be HTC specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could avoid browser caching to force the download, by using some http header, or appending a random get argument to the URL.

Also, starting from Froyo, to force the download to happen in the foreground, use an intermediary html page with a download button. See this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603508/how-to-to-force-the-browser-to-download-in-foreground).