# How to to force the browser to download in foreground?

Tags: android, browser

in my app which is distributed outside of the market, the user can upgrade by downloading an apk. My app notifies the user when an upgrade is available, and if he/she clicks 'Upgrade', a VIEW intent is then launched with the apk URL.

Server-side, the apk is delivered statically, with mimetype `application/vnd.android.package-archive`.

All this works fine. However, starting from Froyo, the browser exits immediately and performs the download in background. That's quite confusing for the user. Before Froyo, the download was performed in the foreground, and when done it was natural for the user to tap on the downloaded item.

Is there a way to have the browser download in the foreground in Froyo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer to my question. The problem occurs when using a direct URL to the APK, but when using a intermediary html page with a download button, the download is then performed in the foreground.